# How to create a deck of cards, have them 'shuffled' and then have two players pick the top two cards

Tags: python

I'm, trying to create a program where a deck of cards (30 cards in total, which each are labeleld 1-10 and assigned a color of yellow, black and red) are shuffled, and then two players choose a card from the 'top' of the deck.

so far i have this:

```
class Card:
def __init__(self, value, color):
    self.value = value
    self.color = color
```

How exactly do i 'shuffle' the deck then have two players choose the top two cards?

Comment: `random.shuffle()` is what your looking for, its in the standard lib. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, color):
        self.value = value
        self.color = color

#Store all 30 cards in a list
cards=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    cards.append(Card(i,"red"))
    cards.append(Card(i,"black"))
    cards.append(Card(i,"yellow"))

#Shuffle the deck
random.shuffle(cards)

#Get top card:
topCard=cards[-1]
del cards[-1]

print(str(topCard.value) + ", " + topCard.color)
```

Where the card that the player has removed is `topCard`

Comment: Where it says `Get top card`, just repeat it again, but store the result in a new variable, i.e. 
`player1TopCard=cards[-1]`
`del cards[-1]`
`player2TopCard=cards[-1]`
`del cards[-1]`
Test if the `.value` is bigger than the other to see which is higher